# How to send a reply email when recipient clicks button embedded in an email message?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I am doing Excel VBA code to send emails from Outlook. This is working so far.

I would like to add a couple of buttons (or links) inside the email body. The recipient could click on one of them to send a reply into my email box.

I know I can add HTML code inside the email body, but that does not send the email. It creates a new email that the user has to send manually.

How do I code an auto reply button embedded in the email body?

I can use VBA and HTML, but is it possible to trigger an auto send email from HTML whatever the type of email address of the person clicking on that button?

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly from the email and to be honest I'm kind of glad, imagining how this could be mis-used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well I agree with you. Actually,, my colleagues agreed on receiving in a specific email box such auto-reply emails from customers. So that is something which might be detrimental only for the company, but it is intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best what you could do is to use a [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) link in the message body. Email client applications don't allow running any scripts in the message bodies for security reasons.